# SOAP UI call from WSHttpbinding binding

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I need your help to find out how should I access `WSHttpBinding` service from SOAP UI , the binding I am using as given below, I wanted to have client side windows authentication.

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding1">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

However I'm getting bad context error message and after tracing I found the below error.

> The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the
>   action 'http://tempuri.org/#####/####' is incorrect or because the
>   message contains an invalid or expired security context token or
>   because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context
>   token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to
>   inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions
>   prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's
>   binding.

Comment: How have you configured Soap UI?

Comment: based on suggestion given on SOAP ui side it seem they still dont support for wshttp with credential message and client credentialtype window.